# How to do group by on multiple columns including text and create new columns on same data-frame using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I want to create new columns and add that to original data-frame that is calculated by groups using multiple columns from current data frame. Basically something like this in python:

`I want to achieve this using transform, apply, group-by all used at once`

**Group by:** `<< 'c_uid','s_uid','sender'>>`

**Columns to aggreagte:** `<< text, Number>>`

**New Columns :** `<<merged_text, Number_sum>>`

**Condition:** `Aggregate only if <<Sender>> value is consecutive`. Like `agent, agent` or `cust, cust` in group by.

**Original Data-frame**

```
c_uid   s_uid    m_uid(unique)  sender  text                                   Number
1       a         ab            agent   How may I help you?                     10.8
1       a         ac            agent   Please let me know, how can I help you? 0.2
1       a         ad            cust    My account is blocked.                  12
1       a         ae            agent   Please let me look into the same        11.3
1       b         af            cust    Ok. I am waiting                        11.28
1       b         ag            cust    Are you connected?                      4.2
2       c         ah            agent   How may I help you?                      5
2       c         ai            cust    My internet is not working?              8
2       d         af            agent   Your user acccount number?               9
2       e         ag            cust    Here is my account number.              10
2       f         ah            cust    I have given account number, please revert.    11.5
```

`I want to create intermediate table group by <<c_uid, s_uid, sender >> and group text and add Numbers columns if there is consecutive text by sender in that group.`

**Intermediate Table**

```
  c_uid s_uid   m_uid(unique)   sender      text                               merged_text                                                   Number_sum
1   a   ab      agent   How may I help you?         [How may I help you?,Please let me know, how can I help you?].      11
1   a   ac      agent   Please let me know, how can I help you? [How may I help you?,Please let me know, how can I help you?]       11
1   a   ad      cust    My account is blocked.          [My account is blocked.]                        12
1   a   ae      agent   Please let me look into the same        [Please let me look into the same]              11.3
1   b   af      cust    Ok. I am waiting                [Ok. I am waiting,  Are you connected?]             15.48
1   b   ag      cust    Are you connected?          [Ok. I am waiting,  Are you connected?]             15.48
2   c   ah      agent   How may I help you?         [How may I help you?]                       5
2   c   ai      cust    My internet is not working?     [My internet is not working?]                   8
2   d   af      agent   Your user acccount number?      [Your user acccount number?]                    9
2   e   ag      cust    Here is my account number.      [Here is my account number.]                    10
2   f   ah      cust    I have given account number, please revert.[I have given account number, please revert.]            11.5
```

**I want to save this above table and pivot in this way**

`I want to create it like agent and customer response pair within same group by that I did earlier table`

**Pivotted_final Table**. This will also have `Numbers_sum` column.

```
c_uid   s_uid   m_uid(unique)           agent                       ust
1   a   ab      [How may I help you?,Please let me know, how can I help you?]   [My account is blocked.]
1   a   ac      [How may I help you?,Please let me know, how can I help you?]   [My account is blocked.]
1   a   ad      [How may I help you?,Please let me know, how can I help you?]   [My account is blocked.]
1   a   ae      [Please let me look into the same]              NA
1   b   af      NA                              [Ok. I am waiting,  Are you connected?]
1   b   ag      NA                              [Ok. I am waiting,  Are you connected?]
2   c   ah      [How may I help you?]                       [My internet is not working?]
2   c   ai      [How may I help you?]                       [My internet is not working?]
2   d   af      [Your user acccount number?]    
2   e   ag      NA                              [Here is my account number.]
2   f   ah      NA                              [I have given account number, please revert.]
```

**Code:**

I tried something like this but it did not work. It groups all agents and customers text in one segment, but I want only consecutive text to get aggregated.

```
aggregated_data = data.groupby(['c_uid','s_uid','sender'])
aggregated_data=aggregated_data.agg({'text' : lambda x: list(x)}).reset_index()
```

It also changes the original data-frame and I am not able to sum numbers in same code.